# mysql - can I determine or limit the amount of memory query is allowed to use

Tags: mysql

I am running a query that creates a temporary table however the limit is 64mb and I am not able to change the limit due to access permissions etc.  When a large date range is selected the temporary table runs out of space and results in a mysql error.

Is there anyway I can determine the size or amount of memory the query will use before attempting to run the query, so I can avoid the above problem gracefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to limit the size of the temp table directly, except by querying for a smaller number of rows in your base SQL query.

Can you be more specific about the error you're seeing?  MySQL temporary tables can exist in memory up to the *lesser* of [`tmp_table_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [`max_heap_table_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size).  If the temp table is larger, MySQL converts it to an on-disk temp table.

This will make the temp table a lot slower than in-memory storage, but it shouldn't result in an error unless [you have no space available in your temp directory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-create.html).

There's also a lot of [ways MySQL uses memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-use.html) besides temp table storage.  You can tune variables for many of these, but it's not the same as placing a limit on the memory a query uses.

---

The error 1114 indicates that you've run out of space.  If it were an InnoDB table on disk, this probably means you have an ibdata1 file without autoextend defined for the tablespace.  For a memory table, it means you're hitting the limit of max_heap_table_size.

Since you can't change max_heap_table_size, your options are to reduce the number of rows you put into the table at a time, or else use an on-disk temp table instead of in memory.

Also be careful about using the most current release of the major version of MySQL.  I found [bug 18160](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18160) that reports MySQL calculating table size incorrectly for heap tables (which are used for in-memory temp tables).  So for example make certain you're using at least MySQL 5.0.23 or 5.1.10 to get the fix for that bug.

Comment: thanks for your reply, the error message im getting is
[Native code: 1114]
[Native message: The table 'dertemp' is full]

Comment: How would I use on-disk temp table

The start of my query looks like
`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE erebus.dertemp SELECT etc goes here`

I imagine I would need to change the first bit and put `on-disk` in there somehow?

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE erebus.dertemp ENGINE=InnoDB SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a direct way to accomplish this, but you could use the information about the used tables provided by [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) like for example the average row size and then calculate the number of records returned by your query using `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`. If you need to be really save calculate the maximum size of a row by using the columns types.

Maybe it would be easier to check the number of records which can be handled and then either specify a fixed [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) clause or to react on `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`.